fsck error: The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid filesystem
I have an external Toshiba hard disk. I tried to make it a bootable drive, but during the process, it became corrupted. and It wasn't showing up on windows.
I am not able to access it on windows but shows as the /dev/sda in my ubuntu OS. I don't need to recover any data therefore making it usable is my only goal here.
The command sudo fsck /dev/sda gives this response:
fsck from util-linux 2.39.3
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem. 
If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem 
(and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock is corrupt, 
and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Using any of the above suggested commands gives the same response.
How do I make it usable? Does the date 5-feb-23 implies the last day this disk was accessed?
Edit:
lsblk shows it as:
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk

output for sudo parted -l:
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
Model: TOSHIBA External USB 3.0 (scsi)                                    
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 


How did you make the drive bootable, and what does the output of lsblk look like? Check out this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/785007/342980 5-feb-23 is the release date of e2fsck.

@Z0OM i was unable to make it bootable, it was a year back, so i don't remember how I tried. I am sure it was due to lack of knowledge about this.

Your question is unclear! What do you mean by "you tried to make it bootable"?
Did you set the bootable flag with fdisk?
Did you install a Linux system, and it’s not working?
Did you install GRUB on it?

What do you intend to do with the drive? Do you want to install Linux on it, or do you just want to use it as a file system?
Have you set up any file system on it at all? Are there any data on the drive?

@Z0OM yes things were unclear. How about now. Please look through again.
